# CodeIgniter and AJAX form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for my web app and I'm currently stuck with AJAX forms.
I've made an view for my "forget password" modal and it looks like this:

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>users/forgot_pass" method="post" id="forget_pass_form">
    <div class="form_header">
        <h1>Forgot your password?</h1>
    </div>
    <?php if($ajax_error == 0) { ?>
    <div class="front_success">
        <p>Password was succesfully sent to your email address.</p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($ajax_error == 1) { ?>
    <div class="login_error">
        <p>Email address was not found in the database.</p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div id="loading_spinner"></div>
    <p><input type="text" name="to_email" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite" class="user" style="background-postion: -200px; margin-top: 20px;" />
    <input type="submit" name="to_submit" value="Lähetä salasana" class="login_submit" id="forget-pass" /></p>
</form>
```

**And here's my controller for it:**

```
<?php
    class Users extends CI_Controller {
        public function forgot_pass()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['to_submit'])) {
                    $this->load->model('user');
                    $email = $_POST['to_email'];
                    $email_addr = $this->user->get_email_address($email);

                    if($email_addr) {
                        foreach($email_addr as $row) {
                            $this->load->library('email');
                            $this->email->from('me');
                            $this->email->to($email);  
                            $this->email->subject('Testing');
                            $this->email->message('Your password is: ' . $row['password']); 

                            if(!$this->email->send()) {
                                $data['ajax_error'] = 1;
                            } else {
                                $data['ajax_error'] = 0;                                                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('index', $data);
                $this->load->view('footer');

        }   


    }


?>
```

I won't post my Model since I know 100% sure it works and it only contains that one method to check if email is found in the database.

Now I want to make it more dynamic by using AJAX. I want it to echo the success message inside a div if the email address was found in the database and the mail was sent
to that email address, otherwise I want it to echo out the error "User was not found in the database".

**Here's my js file which for now:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#forget_pass_form").on('submit', function(){
        var from = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: from.attr('action'),
            type: from.attr('method'),
            data:$(from).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#loading_spinner").show();
                }
        });
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

The AJAX part itself is working, but I just don't know how to implement those messages. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: echo on ajax 1 or 0, based on condition

Comment: Can you please be little more specific?

Comment: i did some work in answer check that....

Comment: @harsh i guess echo does not works in javascript!

Comment: @B_CooperA harsh wanted to say that check for a response in ajax! put a success function there!

Comment: @sunny i was echo on php (that is controller) and it will work

Comment: @HaRsh then mention it in your comment! You wrote ajax that got us confused

Comment: @sunny ohh sorry for that,echo on controller...

Answer (score 0):

make your html code like this

```
   <div class="front_success" style="display:none">
        <p>Password was succesfully sent to your email address.</p>
    </div>



<div class="login_error" style="display:none">
    <p>Email address was not found in the database.</p>
</div>
```

small change in controller:-

```
                                if($this->email->send()) {

                                    echo '1';

                                } else {

                                    echo '0';  

                                  }
```

so what ever your controller return based on that success function will make the dive show

try to make you ajax code like this :-

```
$.ajax({

        url: from.attr('action'),

        type: from.attr('method'),

        data:$(from).serialize(),

        beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#loading_spinner").show();
                },
        success: function (data) {

   //alert(data);  alert it if you want to check the function output

             if(data == '1'){
   //if the email is send then it return 1 so that you show success msg
              $("#login_success").show();

                }else{
  //if the email is not send then it return 0 so that you show error msg
              $("#front_error").show();

               }
$("#loading_spinner").hide();// hide when ajax complete
             }


    });
```

Comment: if you found any problem in ajax then in success function just alert data variavle

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.. The AJAX part.. It will always give me that error message even though I typed it right. After I remove the Javascript, it will send the email

Comment: ok open that alert(data); and check that which type of error it is

Comment: @B_CooperA do one think comment your $this->load->view all three lines if forgot_pass() is not loading the page current forget password page...if it is loading  them let me know ...
why comment because these three line generate your page in ajax so the whole source code come in alert(data)

Comment: I commented them out, and now it's alerting a blank alert box

Comment: may be your
 if($email_addr) 
 this condition is false so its not coming  in it and loop and condition 
echo some think in the this "if($email_addr)" condition to check that it is coming in the condition or not and check output in alert

Comment: $email_addr this is an array so put if(!empty($email_addr)) { it will be better

Comment: But the PHP part is working, I've tested it without that jQuery ajax function and it works

Comment: if it is working then it should go in the else condition